# Sending JSON Array via PHP (Campaign Monitor)

Tags: php, arrays, json, email, campaign-monitor

I have a sample JSON Array labeled sample.txt that is sent from a sweepstakes form that captures a user's name and e-mail. I'm using WooBox so the JSON Array sends information over by each entry, so there are two entries here: http://pastebin.ca/3409546

On a previous question, I was told to break the ][ so that JSON_ENCODE can figure the separate entries. I would like to capture just the name and e-mail and import the array to my e-mail database (campaign monitor).

My question is: How do I add JSON variable labels to an array? If you see my code, I have tried to use the label $email. Is this the correct form or should it be email[0] with a for loop?

```
 $url = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/sweeps/test.txt';
 $content = file_get_contents($url);
 $json = json_decode($content,true);

 $tmp = explode('][', $json_string);
 if (!count($tmp)) {
 $json = json_decode($json_string);

 var_dump($json);
 } else {
 foreach ($tmp as $json_part) {
    $json = json_decode('['.rtrim(ltrim($json_string, '['), ']').']');

    var_dump($json);
}
}
 require_once 'csrest_general.php';
 require_once 'csrest_subscribers.php';

 $auth = array(
 'api_key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
 $wrap = new CS_REST_Subscribers('xxxxxxxxxx', $auth);
 $result = $wrap->add($json(
'EmailAddress' => $email,
'Name' => $custom_3_first,
'Resubscribe' => false
 ));
```

https://github.com/campaignmonitor/createsend-php/blob/master/samples/subscriber/add.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should have been fairly easy: if you have a JSON string and you call `json_decode($string, true)` on it, you get its equivalent in a PHP variable, plain and simple. From there, you can access it like you would any PHP array, object, etc.

The problem is, **you don't have a proper JSON string**. You have a string that looks like JSON, but isn't valid JSON. Run it through a [linter](http://jsonlint.com/) and you'll see what I mean.

PHP doesn't know what to do with your supposed JSON, so you have to resort to manual parsing, which is not a path I would recommend. Still, you were almost there.

```
require_once 'csrest_general.php';
require_once 'csrest_subscribers.php';

$auth = array('api_key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$wrap = new CS_REST_Subscribers('xxxxxxxxxx', $auth);

$url = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/sweeps/test.txt';
$content = file_get_contents($url);    
$tmp = explode('][', $content);
foreach ($tmp as $json_part) {
   $user = json_decode('['.rtrim(ltrim($json_string, '['), ']').']', true);
   $result = $wrap->add(array(
        'EmailAddress' => $user->email,
        'Name' => $user->fullname,
        'Resubscribe' => true
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you give some more detail why manual parsing is something you wouldn't recommend?

Comment: A non-standard JSON string means you have to use a non-standard way to parse it (as above), which means unnecessary code, which makes it harder to understand and maintain. You can have exceptions, but dealing with non-standard JSON doesn't seem like a worthy exception to me. And why do you have a non-standard JSON response? Can't you refactor it? Or, in case it's not in your control, can you guarantee it won't be fixed in the future? Because if it is, the code above will break.

Comment: I believe I've noticed the issue as to why it's a non-standard JSON string. Depending on the time of entries, a new bracket will appear if there has been no entry over 10 minutes. As seen here: http://pastebin.com/ZHb49VT0

I know this is not part of the question, but can you give some insight or documentation on how to replace the ][ with a comma? I think if I can trim the ][ and add a comma it will become a standard JSON string no matter what time an entry gets inputted.

Comment: Who is generating that JSON? Surely not Campaign Monitor... I don't know what documentation I should read in order to point you in the right direction.

Comment: woobox, they recommended adding a new line between every JSON string. I actually did a str_replace seen here: http://paste.ofcode.org/BEcaNGKvemVz7H2se4HLkJ but am still getting errors

Comment: Still feels like manual parsing to me, so I'd stick with this for now. Maybe ask devs on WordPress SE if they can help you with woobox.